# Lenovo T420 TrackPoint "Mous Buttons" not working correct

Tags: touchpad, lenovo, trackpoint

i have a problem with my "new" second hand Lenovo T420. When i use the Track Point while the left "mouse Button" for the track point is pressed pages are scrolled up and down. Also i cant drag and drop windows or folders using the left mouse button. If i use the button in combination with the touchpad it behaves "natural" i can drag and drop or can select multiple folders.

I also have a T43 so i know this is not a "default" behavior. On the T43 i am running Lubuntu 14.04 LTS. On The T420 i am running 15.10. Is there a difference?

How can i disable the Scrolling when using the track point.I would like it to behave like a standard mouse.

Already tried some tricks with the xmodmap.
But nothing helped. Anyone got a Idea? Is the keyboard damaged?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think i did it.

In `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/11-evdev-trackpoint.conf` I changed the option `"EmulateWheel" to false.`

Also changed the comment:

```
  #trackpoint users want wheel emulation
```

=)